# diferença de código de barras de boleto registrado php

Tags: php, boleto

Existe diferença entre o código de barras de um boleto registrado para o boleto que não é registrado?
Hoje, sabemos que não se gera mais boleto que não seja registrado, gostaria de utilizar o modelo que tem em boletophp.com.br, mas, como é sabido, somente gera boleto sem registro. 
Se existe uma diferença no código de barras, seria então necessário saber como é o layout desse codigo de barras para cada banco?

Comment: Pesquisando, descobri, que os mesmo boletos que são mostrados em [link]boletophp.com.br pode ser utilizado sem problemas para os registrados, sendo que o que faz a diferença é o envio de um arquivo para o banco do referido boleto.

Comment: Olá Edson. Tudo bem? Estou na mesma luta hoje para resolver esse problema. Você chegou a resolver? Pois devo usar também o Boleto PHP. Entendo que terei que gerar o arquivo de remessa e retorno, criar o código não seria o problema, mas gostaria de saber se é possível usar o Boleto PHP e onde posso obter os modelos de retorno e remessa. Obrigado!

Comment: Bom dia, me perdoe pela extrema demora para responder, estive afastado do trabalho, por motivos medicos. Sim consegui resolver, utilizando o sistema de boletos php, o codigo de barras serve tanto para o registrado, como para não registrado. O que muda são as regras do arquivo de retorno  e envio para o banco.
Consegui para os principais bancos, santoander, bradesco, itau, caixa e um menos famoso que é o sicred, todos funcionais.

Comment: Olá edson. Certo. Vou usar o boleto php também. obrigado e desde já estimo melhoras.

Comment: Fox.11 veja para o retorno como você disse, varia de sistema para sistema, tem que verificar o manual de cada banco aonde tem todas as instruções para o envio e retorno do arquivo. No meu caso, outra pessoa fez isso em um IDE chamada migui, que é baseada em clipper. Eu só pego o resultado em um arquivo .txt e faço todo o tratamento para processar e transformar em boleto e até em pdf, caso você precise posso te ajudar nessa parte, anota meu watts 11 991799781